# telling if two matrices are congruent and computing the N matric s.t A=N$^T$BN

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-congruences

i guess that to matrices are congruent if and only if they have the same signature, but then if i know that they are congruent, how can i find the N matrix?

for example having $A = \begin{bmatrix}
10 & 7 \\
7 & 5\end{bmatrix} $
And
$B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 5 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$ how can i find N?( i just can do a system of equations or there's another way?)

Comment: Your claim that *“two matrices are congruent if and only if they have the same signature”* is true only for symmetric or Hermitian matrices. A real symmetric matrix is *never* congruent to a non-symmetric real matrix because congruence preserves symmetry/self-adjoint-ness.

Comment: so A and B aren't conruent?

Comment: Of course not.$\,$

Comment: my bad i simply wasted many hours because they simply told me signaature is enough